# initialize a WPF with undefined datatype

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is a class with undefined variable that needs to be passed into the WPF window.

```
 public class SelectedVal<T>
{        
    public T val {get;set;}       
}
```

Window:

```
public partial class SOMEDialogue : Window
{
   public List<SelectedVal<T>> returnlist { get { return FullList; } }
   public List<SelectedVal<T>> FullList = new List<SelectedVal<T>>();       

   public SOMEDialogue (List<SelectedVal<T>> inputVal)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
     }

 }
```

So here is the question, how can I do this properly to get the T and have a global variable set in my WPF?

Edited (code edited too):

The purpose for the WPF is:

- A list of `SelectedVal<T>` input
- Display this input in this WPF
- Depend    on the T type, user can do something about this input
- When finished a return `List<SelectedVal<T>>` returnlist can be
  accessed

Comment: If you need to interact non-generically with your generic class, write a non-generic interface `ISelectedVal { Object Val { get; set; } }`. Have `SelectedVal<T>` [implement it explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). Cast to `ISelectedVal` and use that for your "global variable". This is the classic solution that the .NET framework uses.

Comment: But there is no such thing as a global variable in C#, and your public field `FullList` is not even static. Is `FullList` what you call a "global variable"? It isn't global. Does it need to be? What, exactly, do you need to do with `FullList` (in detail, with code -- more detail than you think I ought to need, more code than you think I ought to need)

Comment: Are you sure you can't do this job with a generic viewmodel (which might have a non-generic base class, or implement a non-generic interface)?

Comment: ok. global var is not the correct terminology....edited it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How do I do this with a generic viewmodel?  Any directions, links to point me to?  Thanks

Comment: How do you do *what* with a generic viewmodel? Tell me what you're trying to do. They're easy to write: It's a generic class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. `public class MyGenericVM<TVM> : ViewModelBase { public SelectedVal<TVM> Whatever { get; set; } }`.

Comment: @Heisenberg You should be able to make this class a generic `SOMEDialogue<T>`. You probably won't be able to use the designer for this window, but if you don't need the designer, just making this class generic should work for you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited, see if it makes sense now?

Comment: @Heisenberg Thanks. I still don't see any code, and "depending on the T type, user can do something about this input" is *exactly* the kind of imponderable neo-expressionist poetry I was trying to warn you against when I said I needed more detail than you think I do. You may notice that the generic typenames are partially eaten by the browser, due to the angle brackets, rendering your bullet points very difficult to parse. You can put backticks around them so they'll be reproduced literally.

Comment: It'll be a lot of code to pile here, e.g if the T is a numeric type, the layout of this WPF will change, and user can filter based on numerical value big or small; if it is a string, the layout is going to be different and user can search based on text they entered.

Comment: @MichaelGunter too bad I do need the designer. Thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg You don't need the designer. Nobody needs the designer. But you don't need a generic window class either. If you're going to have one datatemplate per `T`, you should have a finite set of concrete non-generic classes that have a common generic base class (`class StringVal : SelectedVal<String> {/***/}` etc). Use implicit datatemplates to vary the window content appropriately. Give the common generic base class a non-generic interface as I described above. And please, please, add those backticks. That bullet list is word salad without them.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Let me give a try on the non-generic interface.  My knowledge on that is 0.  Got to learn it from scratch.  Thanks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ++ lol "nobody needs the designer" true!! I loathe cleaning up after people who do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic idea I'm describing. Let me know if you hit any snags. I'm guessing that the search text and the min/max int values are properties of the dialog as a whole. I'm also assuming that there may be a mixture of item types in the collection, which may be an assumption too far. Can you clarify that?

Selected value classes

```
public interface ISelectedVal
{
    Object Val { get; set; }
}
public class SelectedVal<T> : ISelectedVal
{
    public T Val { get; set; }

    object ISelectedVal.Val
    {
        get => this.Val;
        set => this.Val = (T)value;
    }
}
public class StringVal : SelectedVal<String>
{
}
public class IntVal : SelectedVal<int>
{
}
```

Dialog Viewmodel

```
public class SomeDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeDialogViewModel(List<ISelectedVal> values)
    {
        FullList = values;
    }

    public List<ISelectedVal> FullList { get; set; }

    private String _searchText = default(String);
    public String SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _searchText)
            {
                _searchText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _minInt = default(int);
    public int MinInt
    {
        get { return _minInt; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _minInt)
            {
                _minInt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _maxInt = default(int);
    public int MaxInt
    {
        get { return _maxInt; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _maxInt)
            {
                _maxInt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.xaml.cs

```
public SOMEDialogue (List<ISelectedVal> inputValues)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new SomeDialogViewModel(inputValues);
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StringVal}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>Value</Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Val}" />
            <Label>Search text:</Label>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.SearchText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <!-- Other stuff -->
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IntVal}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>Value</Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Val}" />
            <Label>Min value:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.MinIntVal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <Label>Max value:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.MaxIntVal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <!-- Other stuff -->
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding FullList}"
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Heisenberg Make sure it works for you before accepting it! I have a feeling we're a long way from a working implementation. And seriously, those backticks. I shouldn't have had to fix those for you.

Comment: I understand.  I am trying to walk through this.  You are right I am long way from getting it running.